# Controlling the order of static objects' constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

I'm writing a tiny kernel with c++11 and have two instances with the same type which have to be constructed before any other static objects are created.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
// test.hpp
class test {
  // blahblah...
};

// test.cpp
typedef char fake_inst[sizeof(test)] __attribute__((aligned(alignof(test))));

fake_inst inst1;
fake_inst inst2;

// main.cpp
extern test inst1;
extern test inst2;

int kmain() {
    // copy data section

    // initialize bss section

    new (&inst1) test();
    new (&inst2) test();

    // call constructors in .init_array

    // kernel stuffs
}
```

It builds and works as expected without no warning messages, but not with LTO.

I get tons of warning messages complaining the type matching and I wonder if there's a workaround since it confuses me to find the other 'real' warning or error messages.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? In the comments to Pubby's answer below you say you want to initialize several objects of the same type. To me, it seems you would want to initialize structures relating to C++ support, such as the heap, before letting the implementation call other constructors. But that doesn't sound like what you're attempting. Also, what kind of "type matching" do you get warnings about?

Comment: @Potatoswatter a lot of `warning: type of ‘xxx’ does not match original declaration [enabled by default]` things. It's because the actual type is not test but char[]. I thought I could disable static constructor but seems there's no way to do it.

Comment: Ah, I see. What you should do is `char fake_inst1[ sizeof (test) ]; test *const inst1 = reinterpet_cast< test * >( fake_inst1 );`

Comment: The way to disable the static constructor is to put the variable in a wrapper function. The constructor will be called only the first time the wrapper is called. This is very idiomatic and *always* preferred over putting a global at namespace scope. However, in your case you need to make sure the multithreading operations used to implement the "only the first time" functionality are supported at the time this runs.

Comment: Regardless to whether you find a way to suppress your warnings or not, this is IMHO the only **really** correct way to deal with global/static objects with non-trivial c'tor/d'tor. This way not only you control their initialization/destruction order, but also have the actual control of the program flow. For instance, you may throw exceptions from their initialization code and catch them appropriately. And all this without compromising the performance.

Comment: The construction order in C++ is only partially specified, this is why Google "forbids" static global objects of class type: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Static_and_Global_Variables#Static_and_Global_Variables. Instead, they recommend to use a global raw pointer that will never be freed.

Comment: Isn't this a blatant violation of the ODR? Why would one expect this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
// ... .h
template<typename T>
union FakeUnion {
  FakeUnion() {}
  ~FakeUnion() {}

  T inst;
};

extern FakeUnion<test> inst1_;
extern FakeUnion<test> inst2_;
static constexpr test& inst1 = inst1_.inst;
static constexpr test& inst2 = inst2_.inst;
// ... .h end

// ... .cpp
FakeUnion<test> inst1_;
FakeUnion<test> inst2_;
// ... .cpp end
```

Within `main`, you can then say `new (&inst1) test;`. It should not give warnings about type inconsistency violations anymore now, because unlike in your code, this code does not contain variables that have different types in different files.

Comment: While this does solve the name conflict, it does not ensure that the constructor of `inst1` and `inst2` are called before any other.

Comment: @Matt if he calls them in `main` with placement new, it does ensure so if all other ctors are called after `main` in a controlled manner.

Comment: Can you advice on what is the "magic" happening here? I.e. why do we need an union and why does the union have ctor/dtor?

Answer (score 2):

Could you use GCC's `init_priority` attribute?

```
Some_Class  A  __attribute__ ((init_priority (2000)));
Some_Class  B  __attribute__ ((init_priority (543)));
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html#C_002b_002b-Attributes

Comment: I've read about that but it's hard to manage the order of constructors since the priority things are spread over the source files.

Comment: @kukyakya so the issue is initializing the two objects first, or ordering all global constructors in general?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Actually it's not about just two instances, but more than one instances for the same type, so I can't use singleton pattern. The other static objects' construction order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not offer you ways to manage the order of initialization for global objects across multiple files. If you need to manage the order of initialization of these objects this tightly, then I would strongly advise you to *not* make them global objects. Make them global functions that contain static objects and return pointers to them.

But even then, that's less dangerous than full-on manual initialization. Just make a few pointers to those objects available to those who need them (preferably not globally), and you'll be fine.

Comment: I considered using global functions returning the reference or pointer to function-scope static objects but the compiler generates acquire/release things to create the instance and the acquire/release stuffs are implemented with kernel mutex, which can't be used in the kernel initialization.

Comment: @kukyakya: Then you're going to have to initialize these objects manually. That's the only way to be sure without kernel mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// in an .h file

typedef char fake_inst[sizeof(test)] __attribute__((aligned(__alignof__(test))));

extern fake_inst fake_inst1;
extern fake_inst fake_inst2;

inline test& f_inst1() { return *reinterpret_cast<test*>(fake_inst1); }
inline test& f_inst2() { return *reinterpret_cast<test*>(fake_inst2); }

// and for readability

static test& inst1 (f_inst1());
static test& inst2 (f_inst2());
```

Hopefully both `inst1` and `f_inst1()` will be optimized out.

Comment: This is exactly the way i'm using, but I wonder if there is a neater way. I want global objects like `std::cout` or `std::cin` because it seems more readable than instance returning function.

Comment: maybe try a global reference variable, initialized to the retval of `inst1`? This is also optimized (in msvc)

Comment: The problem with global variables is their init order, which is what we're trying to solve...

Comment: @n.m.: correct point. But in this particular case it's ok. The reference itself is a global variable, which is initialized before `main` to the placeholder.